# External ID not found in the system: training.training_odoo_menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-12

so i'm in a training, and i got task to create some custom module, it works well when the code still like this

models.py

```
class Kursus(models.Model):
    _name = 'training.kursus'
     
    name = fields.Char(string="Judul", required=True)
    description = fields.Text()

class Sesi(models.Model):
    _name = 'training.sesi'
     
    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    start_date = fields.Date()
    duration = fields.Float(digits=(6, 2), help="Durasi Hari")
    seats = fields.Integer(string="Jumlah Kursi")
    instructor_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Instruktur")
```

and the view.xml is like this :

```
<odoo>
    <data>
    <!-- ### Membuat Tampilan Tree/List Sesi ### -->
     
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="sesi_tree_view">
        <field name="name">training.sesi.tree</field>
        <field name="model">training.sesi</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Sesi List">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="start_date"/>
                <field name="duration"/>
                <field name="seats"/>
                <field name="instructor_id"/>      
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
     
     
    <!-- ### Membuat Tampilan Form Sesi ### -->
         
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="sesi_form_view">
        <field name="name">training.sesi.form</field>
        <field name="model">training.sesi</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Sesi Form">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="start_date"/>
                        <field name="duration"/>
                        <field name="seats"/>
                        <field name="instructor_id"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
     
     
    <!-- ### Membuat Action/Event Object Sesi ### -->
     
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="sesi_list_action">
        <field name="name">Sesi</field>
        <field name="res_model">training.sesi</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
     
     
    <!-- ### Membuat Sub Menu Sesi ### -->
     
    <menuitem id="sesi_menu" name="Sesi" parent="training_odoo_menu" action="sesi_list_action"/>
    
    </data>
    </odoo>
```

but when i updated the models.py into like this, like my code below, it gain an error, the error is on the last of this question

```
    class Kursus(models.Model):
        _name = 'training.kursus'
     
        name = fields.Char(string="Judul", required=True)
        description = fields.Text()
        session_ids = fields.One2many('training.sesi', 'course_id', string="Sesi")
    
    class Sesi(models.Model):
        _name = 'training.sesi'
         
        name = fields.Char(required=True)
        start_date = fields.Date()
        duration = fields.Float(digits=(6, 2), help="Durasi Hari")
        seats = fields.Integer(string="Jumlah Kursi")
        instructor_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Instruktur")
        course_id = fields.Many2one('training.kursus', ondelete='cascade', string="Kursus", required=True)

and the view.xml like this

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="kursus_form_view">
    <field name="name">training.kursus.form</field>
    <field name="model">training.kursus</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Kursus Form">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="name"/>
                </group>
                <notebook>
                    <page string="Keterangan">
                        <field name="description"/>
                    </page>
                    <page string="Sesi">
                        <field name="session_ids">
                            <tree string="Daftar Sesi">
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="instructor_id"/>
                            </tree>
                            <form>
                                <group string="Informasi">
                                    <field name="name"/>
                                    <field name="instructor_id"/>
                                </group>
                                <group string="Jadwal">
                                    <field name="start_date"/>
                                    <field name="duration"/>
                                    <field name="seats"/>
                                </group>
                            </form>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
 
 
 
 
<!-- ### Membuat Tampilan Tree/List Sesi ### -->
 
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sesi_tree_view">
    <field name="name">training.sesi.tree</field>
    <field name="model">training.sesi</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Sesi List">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="course_id"/>
            <field name="start_date"/>
            <field name="duration"/>
            <field name="seats"/>
            <field name="instructor_id"/>      
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
 
 
<!-- ### Membuat Tampilan Form Sesi ### -->
     
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sesi_form_view">
    <field name="name">training.sesi.form</field>
    <field name="model">training.sesi</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Sesi Form">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <group string="Informasi">
                        <field name="course_id"/>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="instructor_id"/>
                    </group>
                    <group string="Jadwal">
                        <field name="start_date"/>
                        <field name="duration"/>
                        <field name="seats"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

 
<!-- ### Membuat Action/Event Object Sesi ### -->
 
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="sesi_list_action">
    <field name="name">Sesi</field>
    <field name="res_model">training.sesi</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
 
 
<!-- ### Membuat Sub Menu Sesi ### -->
 
<menuitem id="sesi_menu" name="Sesi" parent="training_odoo_menu" action="sesi_list_action"/>

  </data>
</odoo>
```

i got this error when i upgraded module in odoo
Error:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 88, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x7fec8f847d90>, 'training.training_odoo_menu')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 455, in _tag_menuitem
    menu_parent_id = self.id_get(rec.get('parent',''))
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 741, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 747, in model_id_get
    return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1404, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-25>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 93, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1393, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: training.training_odoo_menu

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-67>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/base/models/ir_module.py", line 622, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/base/models/ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 802, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 865, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 755, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 764, in parse
    exc_info[2]
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 455, in _tag_menuitem
    menu_parent_id = self.id_get(rec.get('parent',''))
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 741, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 747, in model_id_get
    return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1404, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
  File "<decorator-gen-25>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/odoo-12/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 93, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/ORIGINAL12/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1393, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: training.training_odoo_menu" while parsing /home/fauz2n/odoo/addons/NDT/training/views/views.xml:159, near
<menuitem id="sesi_menu" name="Sesi" parent="training_odoo_menu" action="sesi_list_action"/>
```

so can anyone help me? if there is anybody that have the same problem can you share about the solutions please

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the menuitem:

```
<menuitem id="sesi_menu" name="Sesi" parent="training_odoo_menu" action="sesi_list_action"/>
```

This has the attribute `parent="training_odoo_menu"`, however, I cannot see the parent menu item in the view?

If you want this menuitem to be the menu root, you would want to remove the parent attribute. If this exists in another module make sure that file is processed first in the manifest.

If you need anything clarifying let me know,

Thanks,